# Which champions scale with kills in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I'm talking about skills like

- **Sion**'s *Enrage*:
  TOGGLE: While toggled on, Sion has increased attack damage at the cost of some health for each autoattack. While Enrage is active, Sion permanently increases his maximum health whenever he kills a unit with either his attacks or abilities. This effect is doubled against champions and large units. **or**
- **Nasus**' *Siphoning Strike*:
  ACTIVE: Nasus' next attack within 10 seconds will deal additional physical damage. Siphoning Strike permanently gains 3 damage if it kills an enemy unit. This bonus is doubled for killing champions, large minions and large monsters

which can scale **indefinitely**.

Is there some comprehensive list of those champions somewhere? I was unable to find it so far.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a widely used mechanic, but there are two other champions so far that can scale indefinitely.

**Thresh**'s *Damnation*: passive allows him to collect souls from nearby slain enemies, either by walking near them, or with the Lantern from Dark Passage.

**Veigar**'s *Baleful Strike*: Passive: Veigar gains permanent bonus ability power when he kills a champion from any source of damage. This stacks with the active ability's AP gain. Active: Unleashes dark energy at target enemy, dealing magic damage. If this ability deals a killing blow, Veigar gains 1 ability power permanently. This bonus is doubled for large minions, large monsters, and champions.

Veigar ability text quoted from [the League of Legends wiki.](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Veigar)

Comment: And that's all?

Comment: Yes, that's all there are so far, including the two named in the question.

Comment: You could count Cho'Gath - kills with his Ulti give him HP, although the stacks are limited to 6 and are halved on death.

Comment: @Hackworth I was assuming due to the indefinite scaling comment, and the fact that he didn't mention items, like Mejai's Soulstealer, that capped stacks didn't count. If you feel they would add something to my answer, let me know and I'll edit them in, or you can, if you'd prefer.

Comment: Yea I gave some emphasis to the "indefinitely" part.

Comment: maybe you could add, that the effectiveness on thresh's indefinite scaling decreases, while veigar, nasus and sion always gain a flat amount of additional ap/dmg/hp

Comment: @Vogel612 As of the 3.10 patch it no longer diminishes, it is set at .75 throughout: http://beta.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-310-notes